# Problem with refreshing in PowerBi after updating MariaDB

Tags: powerbi, mariadb, powerbi-desktop, mysql-connector

After an update of MariaDB 10.5.x to 10.11.4 I run into an errormessage when I want to refresh my reports in PowerBi. The message is saying:
--**An error occurred while reading data from the provider: Object cannot be converted from DBNull to other types.**--

When I use the refresh-button again, the next message says:
--**An error occurred while reading data from the provider: The given key is not present in the dictionary.**--

(Sorry if the translation isn't exactly correct. I translated from my Dutch-version using Google Translate)

This results in a loop of the same two messages, when I keep trying to refresh.

I tried updating the MySQL Connector from MySQL Connector NET 8.0.28 to 8.2.0 but that didn't help. So I am back to 8.0.28

**Is there anyone who has had this happen and resolved the issue?**

Our hostingcompany hasn't replied yet to the question to go back to MariaDB 10.5.x but I think that won't be an option: we are running a webshop on this database and the update has been done a couple of days ago, so any backup is already missing lots of orders and information...

Comment: This sounds like a powerquery error. Open PQ and it will probably be in the first one or two steps of one of your queries.

Comment: [incompatibility](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109331) - can you replace the package MySql.Data by MySqlConnector (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for that trouble. The underlying problem is tracked under https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31608, already fixed, fix will be out in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not thát technical with this kind of things, but does 'tracked' mean it is acknowledged but not yet fixed? I try to pull someone near me (probably from our hostingcompany) to help me understand the technical details in this link you sent.

Comment: acknowledged and fixed. The fix will be available within next couple of weeks, with the next MariaDB Server update.

Comment: 10.11.7 will be the version with the fix.

Comment: Now the fixed version is released.